# Python make clusters of synonyms

Tags: python, nlp, cluster-analysis, wordnet

I have a long list of words :

```
verbs = ['be','have', 'find', 'use', 'show', 'increase', 'detect', 'do', 'determine', 'demonstrate', 'observe','suggest', ...]
```

And I want to make clusters from these words based on which ones are synonyms (semantically close). I want to compare each element of the list with all the rest and for those that have a similarity score > 0.7 , group them together. I am using wordnet but I keep getting this error:

```python
for i, verb in enumerate(verbs):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(verbs)):
        verbs[i].wup_similarity(verbs[j])


    ERROR MESSAGE : 
    ---->        verbs[i].wup_similarity(verbs[j])
    ---->        AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'wup_similarity'
```

Maybe that's not even the right approach, but can anyone help?

Comment: Because you are trying to call `wup_similarity`, which is a method of `synsets`, from `verbs[i]`, which, from your definition, is a string. Your whole loop looks weird, you are nesting 5 for loops, but only using the variables from the first 2. Probably you want to call `syni.wup_similarity(synj)` and cut the last to for loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the updated question, this solution works on my machine.

```
verbs = ['be','have', 'find', 'use', 'show', 'increase', 'detect', 'do', 'determine', 'demonstrate', 'observe','suggest']

for i, verb in enumerate(verbs):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(verbs)):
        v1 = wordnet.synset(verbs[i]+ '.v.01')
        v2 = wordnet.synset(verbs[j]+ '.v.01')
        wup_score = v1.wup_similarity(v2)
        if wup_score > 0.7:
            print(f"{verbs[i]} and {verbs[j]} are similar")
            #or do whatever you want to do with similar words.
```

Regarding the original question:

I'am no expert in this, so maybe this does not help at all. Currently you do `str.wup_similarity(str)`. However according to [this](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) documentation (search for 'wup_similarity' on that website) I think it should be `synset1.wup_similarity(synset2)`.

So my proposal would be to do:

```
for i, verb in enumerate(verbs):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(verbs)):
        for syni in wordnet.synsets(verb[i]):
            for synj in wordnet.synsets(verb[j]):
                for li in syni.lemmas():
                    for lj in synj.lemmas():
                        v1 = wordnet.synset(verbs[i]+ '.v.01')
                        v2 = wordnet.synset(verbs[j]+ '.v.01')
                        v1.wup_similarity(v2)
```

Comment: Hi, I get this error when I try your solution : `---> v1 = wordnet.synset(verbs[i]+ '.v.01')` `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`

Comment: @joasa are you sure the definition of `verbs` as provided in your question is correct? `verbs[i]` should be a string, not a list. Can you do: `print(type(verbs[i]))`?

Comment: Yes you're right. Now `verbs[i]` is a string but I get an error at this line `for synj in wordnet.synsets(verb[j]):` which is `IndexError: string index out of range`.

Comment: @joasa What are `syni`, `synj`, `li` and `lj` for anyway? You don't use those anywhere.

Comment: Yeah true, I was just trying things out and forgot to remove them. Will update my question

Comment: @joasa I updated my answer. The code works on my machine, can you run it and check wheter this does what you need? If so, feel free to accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: yes, thank you!